# Efficient data structure(s) for kind of scripting application?

Tags: c++, algorithm, class, optimization

In C++ I want to write an application that works similar to a scripting language:
Out of some input during "setup time" it will define on a big global array where each variable will be located and on a different array the sequence of the functions ("LogicElement") to call (including their parameters like the variables to use).

One implementation might look like:

```
class LogicElement_Generic
{
public:
  virtual void calc() const = 0;
};

class LogicElement_Mul : public LogicElement_Generic
{
  int &to;
  const int &from1;
  const int &from2;

public:
  LogicElement_Mul( int &_to, const int &_from1, const int &_from2 ) : to(_to), from1(_from1), from2(_from2)
  {}

  void calc() const
  {
    to = from1 * from2;
  }
};

char globalVariableBuffer[1000]; // a simple binary buffer
LogicElement_Generic *le[10];

int main( void )
{
  // just a demo, this would be setup from e.g. an input file:
  int *to    = (int*)globalVariableBuffer;
  int *from1 = (int*)(globalVariableBuffer + sizeof(int));
  int *from2 = (int*)(globalVariableBuffer + 2*sizeof(int));

  *from1 = 2;
  *from2 = 3;

  le[0] = new LogicElement_Mul( *to, *from1, *from2 );

  // doing all calculations:
  // finally it would be a loop iterating over all calculation functions,
  // over and over again - the area in the code where all the resources
  // would be burned...
  le[0]->calc();

  return *to;
}
```

Although that works as intended, looking at the created assembly:

```
  78                    .section    .text._ZNK16LogicElement_Mul4calcEv,"axG",@progbits,_ZNK16LogicElement_Mul4calcEv,comdat
  79                    .align 2
  80                    .weak   _ZNK16LogicElement_Mul4calcEv
  82                _ZNK16LogicElement_Mul4calcEv:
  83                .LFB6:
  17:.../src/test.cpp ****   void calc() const
  84                    .loc 1 17 0
  85                    .cfi_startproc
  86 0000 55            pushq   %rbp
  87                .LCFI6:
  88                    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
  89                    .cfi_offset 6, -16
  90 0001 4889E5        movq    %rsp, %rbp
  91                .LCFI7:
  92                    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
  93 0004 48897DF8      movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
  18:.../src/test.cpp ****   {
  19:.../src/test.cpp ****     to = from1 * from2;
  94                    .loc 1 19 0
  95 0008 488B45F8      movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
  96 000c 488B4008      movq    8(%rax), %rax
  97 0010 488B55F8      movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
  98 0014 488B5210      movq    16(%rdx), %rdx
  99 0018 8B0A          movl    (%rdx), %ecx
 100 001a 488B55F8      movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
 101 001e 488B5218      movq    24(%rdx), %rdx
 102 0022 8B12          movl    (%rdx), %edx
 103 0024 0FAFD1        imull   %ecx, %edx
 104 0027 8910          movl    %edx, (%rax)
  20:.../src/test.cpp ****   }
 105                    .loc 1 20 0
 106 0029 5D            popq    %rbp
 107                .LCFI8:
 108                    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
 109 002a C3            ret
 110                    .cfi_endproc
```

Looking at the assembly lines 95 .. 104 you can see that for each variable three indirections are used.

As this part of the code (the calc() methods) would finally be called very rapidly I want to use the least CPU cycles and memory bandwidth as possible (by general C/C++).

I also want to achieve (not shown in the code above) to have two variable buffers that have exactly the same layout to be able to do double buffering at an multithreaded approach to limit the necessary locks (exact implementation details would be too much detail for this question).

So the big questions are:

- How can I change the architecture to reduce the amount of memory indirections in the calc()?
  (I'd expect only two: one to get the offset address in the variable array and an additional to get the variable itself - but my experiments changing the code above to use offsets made things far worse!)
- Is there a better way to set up the classes and thus the array of the LogicElements so that calling the calculation methods will use the least amount of resources?

Comment: Crucial step in measurement performance; actually measuring performance.  I see no test results here.  And on a side note; why are you storing references to `int`s?  Good way to end up with invalid data and you're not gaining anything.

Comment: 3 indirections per variable are actually pretty good as interpreters go. Thank god there aren't multiple types.

Comment: @Ed S.: you are right that to figure out the critical parts measurements are necessary. But the situation is slightly different here: it's a global design / architecture question and not a local optimisation one. And what should we compare those numbers to? A native implementation? My pathetic try with the offsets? Thanks about the references, I'll try w/o them again

Comment: @delnan: There will be multiple types - but they'll be known at setup time and result in different `calc()` functions/methods. (It's nice to know that 3 are good - but I'm know it could be done with less. But how do I achieve that with a high language like C or C++?!?)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the hint by @Ed S. I changed away from references (where I hoped the compiler could optimize better).

But an even more important step I did was to compare the assembly that was generated after activating optimizations (just a simple `-O2` did do).
(I didn't do that at the beginning as I wanted to have a clearer picture on the generated "pure" machine code and not one where an intelligent compiler fixes a stupid programmer - but it seems the compiler is too "stupid" then...)

So the current result is quite good now for the variable array:

```
class LogicElement_Generic
{
public:
  virtual void calc(void * const base) const = 0;
};

class LogicElement_Mul : public LogicElement_Generic
{
  int const to;
  int const from1;
  int const from2;

public:
  LogicElement_Mul( int const _to, int const _from1, int const _from2 ) : to(_to), from1(_from1), from2(_from2)
  {}

  void calc(void * const base) const
  {
    *((int*)(base+to)) = *((int*)(base+from1)) * *((int*)(base+from2));
  }
};

char globalVariableBuffer[1000]; // a simple binary buffer
LogicElement_Generic *le[10];

int main( void )
{
  int to    = 0;
  int from1 = sizeof(int);
  int from2 = 2*sizeof(int);

  *((int*)(globalVariableBuffer+from1)) = 2;
  *((int*)(globalVariableBuffer+from2)) = 3;

  le[0] = new LogicElement_Mul( to, from1, from2 );
  le[0]->calc(globalVariableBuffer);

  return *((int*)(globalVariableBuffer+to));
}
```

with the relevant part of the assembly:

```
  17:.../src/test.cpp ****   void calc(void * const base) const
  12                    .loc 1 17 0
  13                    .cfi_startproc
  14                .LVL0:
  18:.../src/test.cpp ****   {
  19:.../src/test.cpp ****     *((int*)(base+to)) = *((int*)(base+from1)) * *((int*)(base+from2));
  15                    .loc 1 19 0
  16 0000 4863470C      movslq  12(%rdi), %rax
  17 0004 48634F10      movslq  16(%rdi), %rcx
  18 0008 48635708      movslq  8(%rdi), %rdx
  19 000c 8B0406        movl    (%rsi,%rax), %eax
  20 000f 0FAF040E      imull   (%rsi,%rcx), %eax
  21 0013 890416        movl    %eax, (%rsi,%rdx)
  20:.../src/test.cpp ****   }
  22                    .loc 1 20 0
  23 0016 C3            ret
  24                    .cfi_endproc
```

So I recon the first questions as answered! :)

The second is still open.
(Even more now as the pointer arithmetic might be valid C++ - but very ugly...)